# Making a Python RTL Textbox in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, right-to-left

I am making a basic python Tkinter calculator and I need to know how to force the Textbox I have made to be Right to Left because that is what most calculators use. Is their a *simple* way to do this?

Comment: That Duplicated link solved it! Thanks +rid

Answer (score 0):

It is as simple as
justify='right'